# Two-Dimensional Array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, input

How to input a two-dimensional array in Ruby?How to initialize and declare the array in Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

You declare a 2 dimensional array with

```
tda = [[ 1, 2 ], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Or you can use the `Matrix` class

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html

Comment: This is called a jagged array in some languages (C#, at least), because it doesn't guarantee its rectangular "shape". At the same time, C# offers true 2d rectangular arrays. Just dumping my brain here. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That's why Ruby get us a beautiful `Matrix` class :)

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call `Matrix` a beautiful class; it's not even mutable.